# Problema con código

Tags: c, programación-funcional

Estoy programando en c un ejercicio importante para clase y al ejecutarlo si introduces una opción el programa se queda esperando a que suceda algo, si lo introduces de nuevo indica que el valor no es correcto y vuelve a mostrar el menú. ¿Como puedo solucionar esto?

````
//Directivas al preprocesador
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
 
//Cabecera de funciones
int solicitarOpcionMenu();

void seleccionarOpcion();

int contarCaracteres(FILE *archivo);

int numeroTotalFilas(FILE *archivo);

int filaMaslarga(FILE *archivo);

bool validarEntero(int opcion, int limite_inferior, int limite_superior, int parametros_leidos, char enter);

bool validarReal(float opcion, int limite_inferior, float limite_superior, float parametros_leidos, char enter);

////int Limpiar_buffer();

//void Limpiar_pantalla();

//Función principal
int main (){

        
    solicitarOpcionMenu();
    
}


//Cuerpo de las funciones

int solicitarOpcionMenu(void){           // Función para escoger opción del menú

        int opcion = 0;                  // Variable donde se guarda el número de la opción correspondiente al escogerla
    
    int limite_inferior = 0;         // Valor mínimo posible para las opciones de menú
    
    int limite_superior = 3;         // Valor máximo para para las opciones de menú

    int parametros_leidos;
    
    char enter;
        
    do {

                printf("*******************************************************************************\n");

                printf("1. Número total de caracteres (contando espacios)\n");
                
        printf("2. Número total de filas\n");

                printf("3. Fila más larga\n");

                printf("0. Salir\n");

                printf("*******************************************************************************\n");
        
        printf("\nIntroduzca el número de la opción que desea:");
        
        parametros_leidos = scanf("%d %c", &opcion, &enter);
        
        printf("%d", opcion);
        if(validarEntero(opcion, limite_inferior, limite_superior, parametros_leidos, enter)==false){


            printf("hola"); 
        
        
        }else{
            
            seleccionarOpcion(opcion);
        }
                
            
    }while(opcion !=0);  // While para que si la opción es mayor de "3" o menor de "0" se mantenga el menú
    

        return 0;  // Devuelve el valor almacenado en la variable opcion

}

void seleccionarOpcion(int opcion_seleccionada){
    
    FILE *archivo;
    int numero_caracteres = 0;
    int numero_filas = 0;
    int numfila_maslarga = 0;

    switch (opcion_seleccionada)      //switch para establecer que se ha de hacer en cada caso, llamando a las funciones propias
    {
    
        case 0: 
            break;

        case 1:
            archivo = fopen("ValoresClimatologicosFINAL.csv", "r");
            if(archivo == NULL){

                         printf("El archivo no existe o no se puede abrir..\n");

                }else{
            numero_caracteres = contarCaracteres(archivo); //La función llama a contarcaracteres y lo guarda
            printf("\nEl número de caracteres totales es: %d\n\n\n", numero_caracteres);
            fclose(archivo);
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            archivo = fopen("ValoresClimatologicosFINAL.csv", "r");
                        if(archivo == NULL){

                                 printf("El archivo no existe o no se puede abrir..\n");

                        }else{
            numero_filas = numeroTotalFilas(archivo);
            printf("\nEl número de filas es: %d\n\n\n", numero_filas);
            fclose(archivo);
            }
            break;
        
        case 3:
            archivo = fopen("ValoresClimatologicosFINAL.csv", "r");
                        if(archivo == NULL){

                                 printf("El archivo no existe o no se puede abrir..\n");

                        }else{
            numfila_maslarga = filaMaslarga(archivo);
            printf("\nLa fila más larga es la número: %d\n\n\n", numfila_maslarga);
            fclose(archivo);
            }
            break;
                
    
    
    
    }   




    
}

int contarCaracteres(FILE *archivo){

/*
    Nombre: contarCaracteres
    
    Descripcion: Función para contar los caracteres totales del archivo, contando linea por linea
    
    return: contador (numero de caracteres)
    @param contador: La empezamos igualando a 0 para no tener problemas. Hará una suma cada vez que el parámetro caracateres encuentre un caracter hasta que llegue al final del archivo. 
        En caso de encontrar un salto de linea lo restamos del contador y devolvemos el valor total almacenado en el contador.
    
    @param caracteres: Recorre todo el documento hasta llegar al final (fgetc y EOF), contando TODOS los caracteres del documento
    
    @autor: 
    @versión: 1.0
    */
    int contador=0;
    char caracteres;
    while(caracteres = fgetc(archivo), caracteres != EOF){
        contador++;
        
        if(caracteres =='\n' || caracteres == '\r'){

            contador--;
        }
    }
    return contador;
}

int numeroTotalFilas(FILE *archivo){
        /*
    Nombre: numeroTotalFilas
    
    Descripcion: Función que cuneta el número total de filas del archivo y lo muestra por pantalla.
    
    return: numero_filas (numero de filas)
    @param numero_filas: La empezamos igualando a 0 para no tener problemas. Hará una suma cada vez que el parámetro car encuentre un salto de linea ('\n'). 
        De esta forma contamos el numero de filas y lo devolvemos en return.
    
    @param caracteres: Recorre todo el documento hasta llegar al final (fgetc y EOF), contando TODOS los caracteres del documento
    
    
    @autor: 
    @version: 1.0
    */
    int numero_filas=0;
    char caracteres;
    while(caracteres = fgetc(archivo), caracteres != EOF){
        
        if(caracteres =='\n'){

            numero_filas++;
        }
    }
    
    return numero_filas;

}

int filaMaslarga(FILE *archivo){
    /*
    Nombre: filaMasLarga
    
    Descripcion: Funcion que nos sirve para contar las filas mediante 3 contadores (Contadorc, Comparador, contadorauxiliar) y una variable para guardar el dato final (Fila_mas_larga). 
El ContadorCar recorre el fichero contando los caracteres hasta el final (fgetc y EOF), por cada caracter que encuentre el contador aumentara. Si ContadorCar encuentra un salto de linea ('\n') El ContadorFilas aumentará y el Contador disminuirá. 
Ademas de esto si el Contador es mayor que el comparador, que es 0, los igualaremos para transpasar los datos y poder vaciar el Contador luego. Despues de igualar Contador y Comparador igualaremos el ContadorFilas a Filas para guardar el dato y sacarlo en el return. 
Pero antes de sacar el return tenemos un print que nos dice cuantos caracteres tiene la fila más larga, que funciona usando los datos del Comparador (que realmente son los que ha leido el Contador).
    
    return: Filas (Valor de la fila más larga).
    @param ContadorCar: Pasa por todo el fichero contando TODOS los caracteres.
    @param Contador: Usando la lectura de ContadorCar cuenta solamente caracteres, sin tener en cuenta los saltos de linea.
    @param ContadorFilas: Cuando el ContadorCar encuentra un salto de linea este aumenta, de esta forma contamos el numero de lineas que hay.
    @param Comparador: Nos sirve para almacenar el valor de Contador una vez acabado y asi poder decir en el printf cuantos caracteres tiene la linea mas larga.
    @param Filas: Lo usamos simplemete para guardar los datos de ContadorFilas y poder sacarlo como valor de la función en el return.
    
    @autor: 
    @version: 1.0
    */
    int contador_caracteres=0;
    int contador =0;
    int contadorauxiliar=0;
    int fila_mas_larga;
    char caracteres;
    
    while(caracteres = fgetc(archivo), caracteres != EOF){
        contador++;
        if(caracteres =='\n'){
        contador--;
        contadorauxiliar++;
        if(contador>contador_caracteres){
            contador_caracteres=contador;
            fila_mas_larga=contadorauxiliar;
        }

            contador = 0;
        }
        
    }
    //printf("la fila mas larga tiene tantos caracteres: %d", contadorc);
    
    return fila_mas_larga;
                
}

bool validarEntero(int opcion, int limite_inferior, int limite_superior, int parametros_leidos, char enter){

    
    
        
    if (parametros_leidos !=2 || enter != '\n' || opcion < limite_inferior || opcion > limite_superior ){
            printf("Valor incorrecto. Introduzca un valor valido.\n");
            //Limpiar_buffer();
            return false;
    }
    
    
        return true;
}

bool validarReal(float opcion, int limite_inferior, float limite_superior, float parametros_leidos, char enter){
      
     if (parametros_leidos !=2 || enter != '\n' || opcion < limite_inferior || opcion > limite_superior ){
                        printf("Valor incorrecto. Introduzca un valor valido.\n");
                        //Limpiar_buffer();
                return false;           
     }
                        
        


                return true;

}

/*int Limpiar_buffer(){
    while(getchar() != '\n'){
    
        return  1;
    }
    return 0;
}
*/
/*void Limpiar_pantalla(){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<25; i++) printf("\n");
}
*/
/*```

CODIGO 2
~~~
//Directivas al preprocesador
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
 
//Cabecera de funciones
int solicitarOpcionMenu();

void seleccionarOpcion();

int contarCaracteres(FILE *archivo);

int numeroTotalFilas(FILE *archivo);

int filaMaslarga(FILE *archivo);

bool validarEntero(int opcion, int limite_inferior, int limite_superior, int parametros_leidos, char enter);

bool validarReal(float opcion, int limite_inferior, float limite_superior, float parametros_leidos, char enter);

int Limpiar_buffer();

//void Limpiar_pantalla();

//Función principal
int main (){
    int opcion;
    
    do{
    opcion=solicitarOpcionMenu();
    seleccionarOpcion(opcion);
    }while(opcion !=0);
    
    return 0;

}


//Cuerpo de las funciones

int solicitarOpcionMenu(){
    int opcion, parametros_leidos;
    char enter;
    int limite_inferior = 0;
    int limite_superior = 3;

        do{
                printf("*******************************************************************************\n");

                printf("1. Número total de caracteres (contando espacios)\n");
                
        printf("2. Número total de filas\n");

                printf("3. Fila más larga\n");

                printf("0. Salir\n");

                printf("*******************************************************************************\n");
                
                printf("introduce una opcion");
                parametros_leidos = scanf("%d%c", &opcion, &enter);
               } while(validarEntero(opcion,limite_inferior, limite_superior, parametros_leidos,enter)==false);
        
    
    return opcion;

}

void seleccionarOpcion(int opcion_seleccionada){
    
    FILE *archivo;
    int numero_caracteres = 0;
    int numero_filas = 0;
    int numfila_maslarga = 0;

    switch (opcion_seleccionada)      //switch para establecer que se ha de hacer en cada caso, llamando a las funciones propias
    {
    
        case 0: 
            break;

        case 1:
            archivo = fopen("ValoresClimatologicosFINAL.csv", "r");
            if(archivo == NULL){

                         printf("El archivo no existe o no se puede abrir..\n");

                }else{
            numero_caracteres = contarCaracteres(archivo); //La función llama a contarcaracteres y lo guarda
            printf("\nEl número de caracteres totales es: %d\n\n\n", numero_caracteres);
            fclose(archivo);
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            archivo = fopen("ValoresClimatologicosFINAL.csv", "r");
                        if(archivo == NULL){

                                 printf("El archivo no existe o no se puede abrir..\n");

                        }else{
            numero_filas = numeroTotalFilas(archivo);
            printf("\nEl número de filas es: %d\n\n\n", numero_filas);
            fclose(archivo);
            }
            break;
        
        case 3:
            archivo = fopen("ValoresClimatologicosFINAL.csv", "r");
                        if(archivo == NULL){

                                 printf("El archivo no existe o no se puede abrir..\n");

                        }else{
            numfila_maslarga = filaMaslarga(archivo);
            printf("\nLa fila más larga es la número: %d\n\n\n", numfila_maslarga);
            fclose(archivo);
            }
            break;
                
    
    
    
    }   




    
}

int contarCaracteres(FILE *archivo){

/*
    Nombre: contarCaracteres
    
    Descripcion: Función para contar los caracteres totales del archivo, contando linea por linea
    
    return: contador (numero de caracteres)
    @param contador: La empezamos igualando a 0 para no tener problemas. Hará una suma cada vez que el parámetro caracateres encuentre un caracter hasta que llegue al final del archivo. 
        En caso de encontrar un salto de linea lo restamos del contador y devolvemos el valor total almacenado en el contador.
    
    @param caracteres: Recorre todo el documento hasta llegar al final (fgetc y EOF), contando TODOS los caracteres del documento
    
    @autor: 
    @versión: 1.0
    */
    int contador=0;
    char caracteres;
    while(caracteres = fgetc(archivo), caracteres != EOF){
        contador++;
        
        if(caracteres =='\n' || caracteres == '\r'){

            contador--;
        }
    }
    return contador;
}

int numeroTotalFilas(FILE *archivo){
        /*
    Nombre: numeroTotalFilas
    
    Descripcion: Función que cuneta el número total de filas del archivo y lo muestra por pantalla.
    
    return: numero_filas (numero de filas)
    @param numero_filas: La empezamos igualando a 0 para no tener problemas. Hará una suma cada vez que el parámetro car encuentre un salto de linea ('\n'). 
        De esta forma contamos el numero de filas y lo devolvemos en return.
    
    @param caracteres: Recorre todo el documento hasta llegar al final (fgetc y EOF), contando TODOS los caracteres del documento
    
    
    @autor: 
    @version: 1.0
    */
    int numero_filas=0;
    char caracteres;
    while(caracteres = fgetc(archivo), caracteres != EOF){
        
        if(caracteres =='\n'){

            numero_filas++;
        }
    }
    
    return numero_filas;

}

int filaMaslarga(FILE *archivo){
    /*
    Nombre: filaMasLarga
    
    Descripcion: Funcion que nos sirve para contar las filas mediante 3 contadores (Contadorc, Comparador, contadorauxiliar) y una variable para guardar el dato final (Fila_mas_larga). 
El ContadorCar recorre el fichero contando los caracteres hasta el final (fgetc y EOF), por cada caracter que encuentre el contador aumentara. Si ContadorCar encuentra un salto de linea ('\n') El ContadorFilas aumentará y el Contador disminuirá. 
Ademas de esto si el Contador es mayor que el comparador, que es 0, los igualaremos para transpasar los datos y poder vaciar el Contador luego. Despues de igualar Contador y Comparador igualaremos el ContadorFilas a Filas para guardar el dato y sacarlo en el return. 
Pero antes de sacar el return tenemos un print que nos dice cuantos caracteres tiene la fila más larga, que funciona usando los datos del Comparador (que realmente son los que ha leido el Contador).
    
    return: Filas (Valor de la fila más larga).
    @param ContadorCar: Pasa por todo el fichero contando TODOS los caracteres.
    @param Contador: Usando la lectura de ContadorCar cuenta solamente caracteres, sin tener en cuenta los saltos de linea.
    @param ContadorFilas: Cuando el ContadorCar encuentra un salto de linea este aumenta, de esta forma contamos el numero de lineas que hay.
    @param Comparador: Nos sirve para almacenar el valor de Contador una vez acabado y asi poder decir en el printf cuantos caracteres tiene la linea mas larga.
    @param Filas: Lo usamos simplemete para guardar los datos de ContadorFilas y poder sacarlo como valor de la función en el return.
    
    @autor
    @version: 1.0
    */
    int contador_caracteres=0;
    int contador =0;
    int contadorauxiliar=0;
    int fila_mas_larga;
    char caracteres;
    
    while(caracteres = fgetc(archivo), caracteres != EOF){
        contador++;
        if(caracteres =='\n'){
        contador--;
        contadorauxiliar++;
        if(contador>contador_caracteres){
            contador_caracteres=contador;
            fila_mas_larga=contadorauxiliar;
        }

            contador = 0;
        }
        
    }
    //printf("la fila mas larga tiene tantos caracteres: %d", contadorc);
    
    return fila_mas_larga;
                
}

bool validarEntero(int opcion, int limite_inferior, int limite_superior, int parametros_leidos, char enter){

    
        
    if (parametros_leidos !=2 || enter != '\n' || opcion < limite_inferior || opcion > limite_superior ){
            printf("Valor incorrecto. Introduzca un valor valido.\n");
            Limpiar_buffer();
            return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
    
}

bool validarReal(float opcion, int limite_inferior, float limite_superior, float parametros_leidos, char enter){
      
     if (parametros_leidos !=2 || enter != '\n' || opcion < limite_inferior || opcion > limite_superior ){
                        printf("Valor incorrecto. Introduzca un valor valido.\n");
                        //Limpiar_buffer();
                return false;           
     }
                        
        


                return true;

}

int Limpiar_buffer(){
    while(getchar() != '\n'){
    
        return  1;
    }
    return 0;
}

/*void Limpiar_pantalla(){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<25; i++) printf("\n");
}
*/
/*
________$$$$
_______$$__$
_______$___$$
_______$___$$
_______$$___$$
________$____$$
________$$____$$$
_________$$_____$$
_________$$______$$
__________$_______$$
____$$$$$$$________$$
__$$$_______________$$$$$$
_$$____$$$$____________$$$
_$___$$$__$$$____________$$
_$$________$$$____________$
__$$____$$$$$$____________$
__$$$$$$$____$$___________$
__$$_______$$$$___________$
___$$$$$$$$$__$$_________$$
____$________$$$$_____$$$$
____$$____$$$$$$____$$$$$$
_____$$$$$$____$$__$$
_______$_____$$$_$$$
________$$$$$$$$$$
*/
~~~
````

Comment: Por favor no coloques texto de relleno que no aporta a la pregunta

Comment: En serio tienes que ver lo que es un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Hacen falta 600 lineas de codigo para reproducir tu problema? En serio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en el scanf que has puesto que en vez de pedir un número pide un número y una letra. Lo de pedir la letra y poner el sacanf igual a un número no te hace ninguna falta.

El error de que te da siempre "el número no es correcto" es porque el if de la función validar Entero no tiene sentido lo que has hecho porque le pasas demasiados datos con pasar el número que ha leido el scanf y los límites ya está todo lo demás sobra.En el if solo tienes que poner que sea mayor o igual que el límite inferior y menor o igual que el inferior. (mayor o igual es así `>=`). Esto último de el menor y el igual lo has puesto alreves también es por eso que no te funciona.

Además tienes la función validar entero repetida la tienes una vez como validar entero y otra vez como validar real y en las dos pone exactamente lo mismo.

Otra cosa que no entiendo es porque si las opciones solo pueden ser números enteros pasas a las funciones que tienes repetidas un número float. No puede llevar coma el número que recoja el scanf porque has puesto %d y &int que són para números enteros. Lo mismo te pasa cuando pasas el límite superior que mandas un float cuando el número que quieres pasar es 3 que es entero.(Float es para pasar un número con coma.)

Cuando en la parte de arriba del programa declaras las funciones solo tienes que poner que tipo de funciones vas a pasar no el nombre quedaría una cosa así:

`void verificar_Entero(int,int,int);`

Cuando pones en la funcion validarentero en el if que se cumplan dos condiciones lo estás haciendo mal se tiene que cumplir una cosa y la otra que no se hace con `||` sino con `&&` y las dos condiciones de a los lados las tendrías que poner entreparentesis cada una así `if( (condicion) && (condicion) )`

En el main tienes puesto un `printf("hola")` que diría que se te ha colado. lo que puedes hacer es poner en ese printf el mensaje de error y sacarlo de la función así queda más limpio y puedes bolver a usar la funcion para ver si un número está en el intervalo o no sin que te ponga el mensaje de error siempre solo cuando haga falta.

Aqui tienes la parte que has dicho que no funcionaba arreglada el resto del programa no se si está bien porque no se que tiene que hacer pero veo alguna cosa un poco sospechosa XD:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int solicitarOpcionMenu();
void seleccionarOpcion();
int contarCaracteres(FILE *archivo);
int numeroTotalFilas(FILE *archivo);
int filaMaslarga(FILE *archivo);
bool validarEntero(int, int, int);

int main (){


    solicitarOpcionMenu();

}

int solicitarOpcionMenu(void){           // Función para escoger opción del menú

    int opcion = 0;                  // Variable donde se guarda el número de la opción correspondiente al escogerla
    int limite_inferior = 0;         // Valor mínimo posible para las opciones de menú
    int limite_superior = 3;         // Valor máximo para para las opciones de menú

    do {

                printf("*******************************************************************************\n");

                printf("1. Número total de caracteres (contando espacios)\n");

        printf("2. Número total de filas\n");

                printf("3. Fila más larga\n");

                printf("0. Salir\n");

                printf("*******************************************************************************\n");

        printf("\nIntroduzca el número de la opción que desea:");

        scanf("%d", &opcion);

        printf("%d", opcion);

        if(validarEntero(opcion, limite_inferior, limite_superior)==false){


        printf("Valor incorrecto. Introduzca un valor valido.\n");

        }else{

            seleccionarOpcion(opcion);
        }


    }while(opcion != 0);


        return 0;

}

void seleccionarOpcion(int opcion_seleccionada){

    FILE *archivo;
    int numero_caracteres = 0;
    int numero_filas = 0;
    int numfila_maslarga = 0;

    switch (opcion_seleccionada)
    {

        case 0:
            break;

        case 1:
            archivo = fopen("ValoresClimatologicosFINAL.csv", "r");
            if(archivo == NULL){

                         printf("El archivo no existe o no se puede abrir..\n");

                }else{
            numero_caracteres = contarCaracteres(archivo);
            printf("\nEl número de caracteres totales es: %d\n\n\n", numero_caracteres);
            fclose(archivo);
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            archivo = fopen("ValoresClimatologicosFINAL.csv", "r");
                        if(archivo == NULL){

                                 printf("El archivo no existe o no se puede abrir..\n");

                        }else{
            numero_filas = numeroTotalFilas(archivo);
            printf("\nEl número de filas es: %d\n\n\n", numero_filas);
            fclose(archivo);
            }
            break;

        case 3:
            archivo = fopen("ValoresClimatologicosFINAL.csv", "r");
                        if(archivo == NULL){

                                 printf("El archivo no existe o no se puede abrir..\n");

                        }else{
            numfila_maslarga = filaMaslarga(archivo);
            printf("\nLa fila más larga es la número: %d\n\n\n", numfila_maslarga);
            fclose(archivo);
            }
            break;




    }





}

int contarCaracteres(FILE *archivo){

/*
    Nombre: contarCaracteres

    Descripcion: Función para contar los caracteres totales del archivo, contando linea por linea

    return: contador (numero de caracteres)
    @param contador: La empezamos igualando a 0 para no tener problemas. Hará una suma cada vez que el parámetro caracateres encuentre un caracter hasta que llegue al final del archivo.
        En caso de encontrar un salto de linea lo restamos del contador y devolvemos el valor total almacenado en el contador.

    @param caracteres: Recorre todo el documento hasta llegar al final (fgetc y EOF), contando TODOS los caracteres del documento

    @autor:
    @versión: 1.0
    */
    int contador=0;
    char caracteres;
    while(caracteres = fgetc(archivo), caracteres != EOF){
        contador++;

        if(caracteres =='\n' || caracteres == '\r'){

            contador--;
        }
    }
    return contador;
}

int numeroTotalFilas(FILE *archivo){
        /*
    Nombre: numeroTotalFilas

    Descripcion: Función que cuneta el número total de filas del archivo y lo muestra por pantalla.

    return: numero_filas (numero de filas)
    @param numero_filas: La empezamos igualando a 0 para no tener problemas. Hará una suma cada vez que el parámetro car encuentre un salto de linea ('\n').
        De esta forma contamos el numero de filas y lo devolvemos en return.

    @param caracteres: Recorre todo el documento hasta llegar al final (fgetc y EOF), contando TODOS los caracteres del documento


    @autor:
    @version: 1.0
    */
    int numero_filas=0;
    char caracteres;
    while(caracteres = fgetc(archivo), caracteres != EOF){

        if(caracteres =='\n'){

            numero_filas++;
        }
    }

    return numero_filas;

}

int filaMaslarga(FILE *archivo){
    /*
    Nombre: filaMasLarga

    Descripcion: Funcion que nos sirve para contar las filas mediante 3 contadores (Contadorc, Comparador, contadorauxiliar) y una variable para guardar el dato final (Fila_mas_larga).
El ContadorCar recorre el fichero contando los caracteres hasta el final (fgetc y EOF), por cada caracter que encuentre el contador aumentara. Si ContadorCar encuentra un salto de linea ('\n') El ContadorFilas aumentará y el Contador disminuirá.
Ademas de esto si el Contador es mayor que el comparador, que es 0, los igualaremos para transpasar los datos y poder vaciar el Contador luego. Despues de igualar Contador y Comparador igualaremos el ContadorFilas a Filas para guardar el dato y sacarlo en el return.
Pero antes de sacar el return tenemos un print que nos dice cuantos caracteres tiene la fila más larga, que funciona usando los datos del Comparador (que realmente son los que ha leido el Contador).

    return: Filas (Valor de la fila más larga).
    @param ContadorCar: Pasa por todo el fichero contando TODOS los caracteres.
    @param Contador: Usando la lectura de ContadorCar cuenta solamente caracteres, sin tener en cuenta los saltos de linea.
    @param ContadorFilas: Cuando el ContadorCar encuentra un salto de linea este aumenta, de esta forma contamos el numero de lineas que hay.
    @param Comparador: Nos sirve para almacenar el valor de Contador una vez acabado y asi poder decir en el printf cuantos caracteres tiene la linea mas larga.
    @param Filas: Lo usamos simplemete para guardar los datos de ContadorFilas y poder sacarlo como valor de la función en el return.

    @autor:
    @version: 1.0
    */
    int contador_caracteres=0;
    int contador =0;
    int contadorauxiliar=0;
    int fila_mas_larga;
    char caracteres;

    while(caracteres = fgetc(archivo), caracteres != EOF){
        contador++;
        if(caracteres =='\n'){
        contador--;
        contadorauxiliar++;
        if(contador>contador_caracteres){
            contador_caracteres=contador;
            fila_mas_larga=contadorauxiliar;
        }

            contador = 0;
        }

    }
    //printf("la fila mas larga tiene tantos caracteres: %d", contadorc);

    return fila_mas_larga;

}

bool validarEntero(int opcion, int limite_inferior, int limite_superior){




    if ((opcion >= limite_inferior) && (opcion >= limite_superior) ){
            return false;
    }

        return true;
}
```

No he tocado las funciones:

-seleccionarOpcion

-filaMaslarga

-numeroTotalFilas

-contarCaracteres

Comment: La función de validarentero y validarreal no entiendo que diferencia tienene, osea como debería utilizar cada una. Por lo demás muchas gracias por la ayuda 

Comment: Lo de los float no sé decirte por qué está. Nos han dado un pdf en el que explica como debemos hacer el programa con las funciones necesarias (Prototipos) y venían así. No sé si es que los profesores como tal no saben programar.

Comment: Estoy editando la pregunta todo el rato porque a la que voy lellendo el programa veo más fallos y te los digo para que entiendas el programa que te voy a pasar XD. No lo digo a mala leche que se que cuando empiezas a programar y tienes un lio en la cabeza es bastante dificil.

Comment: JAJAJA, se agradece cada comentario, aunque no hace más que rallarme con la forma en que nos pidan que hagan los ejercicios. Creo que me he metido en la uni que no es.

Comment: yo tambien lo creo XD pero lo que has hechodel switch está bien

Comment: Tabién te digo que tengo un batiburrillo de ideas en cuanto a todo esto de programación y he estado haciendo este ejercicio entre ayuda de una profesional y un compañero de clase.

Comment: El scanf se iguala a lo de paramtreos leidos creo que básicamente para utilizar esa variable que te dan en algún lado

Comment: Después me han pasdo un código que parece que si lo soluciona pero supongo que aún así tiene fallos

Comment: bueno yo te respondo a la pregunta XD y si algún dia tienes otra y la leo tmbn te la respondo

Comment: Gracias querido ángel de la guarda XD

Comment: He puesto el código 2 pro si quieres verlo.

Comment: la parte que decias que no funcionaba está arreglada no se si lo demás funcionará si tienes un programa que funciona bien remplaza las funciones que digo que no he cambiado por las que hay en el programa que te han mandado.

Comment: He probado el 2 y parece todo correcto. De todos modos voy a ver todo lo que has comentado por qué hace falta xd

Comment: Vale XD me alegro de haber podido ayudarte.

Comment: Claro compa. Una cosa, te parece si mantenemos el contacto por otros medios? Me has parecido la hostia XD.

Comment: Te dejo mi discord: LoboFurioso#0180